# ajax is returning authentication failure for json object in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

this is the getData function  that gets the data from querying
and by a data reader it appends them into a string and later on it returns the string to ajax:

```
 public static string GetData(string Word)
{

    string response = "<p>No customer selected</p>";
    string connect = "Data Source=SAFI-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=work1;Integrated Security=True";
    string sql = "SELECT word_Id  ,word  ,meaning    ,syn1   ,syn2,syn3 ,syn4 FROM trial WHERE word = N'"+Word+"'";
        //" SELECT  tbl_dic.WordID, tbl_dic.Word, tbl_dic.meaning, tbl_dic.syn1, tbl_dic.syn2, tbl_dic.syn3, tbl_dic.syn4, tbl_Trans.Definition, tbl_Trans.Translation FROM tbl_dic INNER JOIN tbl_Trans ON tbl_dic.WordID = tbl_Trans.WordID  where Word=N'" + Word + "'";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Word", Word);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    sb.Append("<p>");
                    sb.Append("<strong>" + rdr["meaning"].ToString() + "</strong><br />");
                    sb.Append(rdr["syn1"].ToString() + "<br />");
                    sb.Append(rdr["syn2"].ToString() + "<br />");
                    sb.Append(rdr["syn3"].ToString() + "<br />");
                    sb.Append(rdr["syn4"].ToString() + "<br />");

                    sb.Append("</p>");
                    response = sb.ToString();
                    conn.Close();

                    return response;
                }
           }
            return "<p style='background-color:black;'>sdadasdasda</p>";
        }
    }
}
```

now the ajax/jquery code :

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#askme").keyup(function () {
        $("#ora").empty();

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "solution1.aspx/GetData",
            data: "{'Word' : '" + $("#askme").val() + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (res) {
                var json1 = JSON.stringify(res);
                alert("sucess");
                console.log(json1);
                $("#ora").html(json1);
 },

            error: function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
               alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
               alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
               alert("status: " + xhr.status);
               alert("text status: " + textStatus);
               alert("error: " + err);
            }

    });


});

    });
```

when success and when console logging res , the following is returned:

```
 {"Message":"Authentication failed.","StackTrace":null,"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

could it be that maybe the visual studio is broken and needs a repair , because i can't see no problem in the code knowing that the query works and i already tried 3 differenet ways to finish the task and every time i get the same object 
note : i have another project written in asp.net mvc and ajax is working perfectly 
plz help !!!!

Comment: I'm assuming the 'authentication failed' when you tried to reach `solution1.aspx/GetData`. I would make sure you can reach that.

Comment: You're running this from Visual Studios and have confirmed you can access the DB with your Windows Credentials correct? This is not running as a different user, it's you and you do indeed have access right?

Comment: no the ajax is succeeding about solution1.apsx/getdata , otherwise it would have gave an error .

Comment: yes i have access to the db , other mvc projects are working perfectly

Comment: i found the solutionThis was driving me crazy.

Inside ~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs change:

settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
To:

settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
console.log(res.d);
```

Try this for appending `res` as `HTML`

```
$("#ora").html($.parseHTML(res.d));
```

All the success Function as

```
 success: function (res) {
                var json1 = $.parseHTML(res.d);
                alert("sucess");
                console.log(res.d));//server method returns the string as You gave So dont stringify the res
                $("#ora").html(json1);
 },
```

Comment: hello , thank you a lot , but i found the solution i should change something in the web config , i did it and it worked .